# How to load Firebase query into ArrayList<> to pass to adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase query to show into a `recyclerView`, but I don`t know which`ValueListener` is supposed to be used for this purpose.

in order to populate my RecyclerView Adapter i need to pass an ArrayList , so how to do so ? how to add items from query into the ArrayList ?

I do not want to use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` because it is much more limted than `RecyclerView.Adapter` (does not meet my needs).

Thanks

Comment: FirebaseUI is an open-source library that contains efficient implementations of a `ListAdapter` and `RecyclerAdapter` for Firebase. Even if you don't want to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter, you can still use its code as the basis for building your own adapter.

Answer (score 2):

```
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference("imageData");//image data is my json array List

myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           //this will be called for every child in your list
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           //this will be called for every child changed in your list
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer  , do i need to kill or detach the listener ? because i tried this method but when i move from tab to another (i use viewpager) when i get back to first tab the items dissappear.

PS: internet connection works fine and firebasePersistant works fine

Answer (score 1):

Just query the values and get it from firebase and use a custom recycler view to populate the queried data...Then you may be looking for this..

```
 mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            recyclerList.clear();
            recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(recyclerList);
            RecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                BTIsdDetails post = postSnapshot.getValue(BTIsdDetails.class);
                BTIsdDetails btIsdDetails = new BTIsdDetails(post.getName(), post.getId());
                isdList.add(btIsdDetails);
                BTLog.d(TAG, " -------------------------- " + post.getName());
            }
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(isdAdapter);
        }
```

Comment: My question is about how to achieve that

Comment: You can query the data based on your requirements and the guidelines are provided in below link...https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Comment: sorry if didn`t explain it in detail enough , in order to populate my RecyclerView Adapter i need to pass an ArrayList , so how to do so ? how to add item into the ArrayList ?